# how to create database in my salesforce's site.com and how to use it?

Tags: database, salesforce

I'm planning to make little web on salesforce that sells e-magazines. But i don't know how to create database and use it. I'm using 30 days free trial of salesforce.

Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce has wrapped database engine which runs under each salesforce org. You do not need any preparation for work with it.

Salesforce database model has the following structure:

- sObject is analog of database table
- sObject's field is analog of database column

Salesforce has a set of default tables(sObject - [Standard Salesforce objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)). You has ability to create your own tables via *Setup --> Create --> Object* and connect these tables with standard or custom via [relationships](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm). Also you have ability to manipulate data via SOQL (SQL like query language)

I would suggest you to read these [tutorials](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook)